# How to prevent query >>> on table being loaded? Django Table

Tags: html, django, postgresql, django-models

This issue has been resolved I had added a extra > to one of my tags. Sometimes that second pair of eyes is all you need to find such a simple mistake.

```
 <table class="table table-striped">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>ID</th>
      <th>Call Time</th>
      <th>Reservation Number</th>
      <th>Stage Name</th>
      <th>Update Call</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
```

Comment: I think that this:`</th>>` is likely to lead to extra `>`, so you could try fixing that.  I don't know why they did up where they do, though.

Comment: That resolved it I just needed a second pair of eyes. Thank you for your help @jjanes